# Unable to start new Nextjs application Failed to load next.config.js

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, npx

I pulled a nextJS application from git and tried starting it using `npm run dev` ,`npx next dev` `npm run start`, matter of fact, every single command I ran gave me the same error.

To further troubleshoot, I followed a youtube tutorial and I started a brand new project ran `npx create-next-app appname` and again. Same error.

`H:\Documents\Projects\React\NextTutorial\ninjalist>npm run dev ninjalist@0.1.0 dev next dev ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000 error - Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error Error: Not supported at Object.loadConfig [as default] (H:\Documents\Projects\React\NextTutorial\ninjalist\node_modules\next\dist\server\config.js:399:74) at async NextServer.loadConfig (H:\Documents\Projects\React\NextTutorial\ninjalist\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:110:22) at async NextServer.prepare (H:\Documents\Projects\React\NextTutorial\ninjalist\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:92:24) at async H:\Documents\Projects\React\NextTutorial\ninjalist\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js:126:9`

Most prominent is it's failing to load `next.config.js`
and the contents of that file is simply

`/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */ module.exports = { reactStrictMode: true, }`

Appreciate if I could be informed on what i'm missing cause I have not written any code, this is straight from the create app and I am getting this error.
Gratitude for the assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it by upgrading to the latest version of NodeJS

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 7):

Dont waste even a single minute. Just update to the latest version of node